# Berks install fails while waiting for connection to supermaket - windows 7

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

When I do a berks install I am getting the error

```
Error retrieving universe from source: https://supermarket.chef.io/
  * [Berkshelf::APIClient::TimeoutError] Unable to connect to: https://supermarket.chef.io/
Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `tar (~> 2.0.0)` required by `user-specified dependency`
Unable to find a solution for demands: java (0.1.0), tomcat (0.1.0), tar (~> 2.0.0)
```

Though I am able to connect to `https://supermarket.chef.io/` through browser but unable to ping `supermarket.chef.io` through cmd.a

Here is my berksfile

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

metadata
cookbook 'java', path: '../java'
cookbook 'tar', '~> 2.0.0'
```